# What would happen if Devil Fruit that Chopper ate were eaten by a human being?

Tags: one-piece

[Wiki about Hito Hito no Mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Hito_Hito_no_Mi):

> The Hito Hito no Mi is a Zoan-type Devil Fruit that allows its user to
>   transform into a human hybrid and a full human at will. It was eaten
>   by Tony Tony Chopper.
>
> By consuming the fruit, Chopper has been given human intelligence,
>   allowing him to understand and communicate in human language. The
>   fruit has also given Chopper the ability to perceive concepts that a
>   reindeer would not comprehend, such as medicine. It also allows him to
>   transform into human/reindeer hybrid forms.

So how about if the fruit were eaten by a human being? Would the effects of Hito Hito no Mi kick in?

And it looks like Chopper ate that fruit by accident?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most likely nothing would happen, that person would lose the ability to swim but would not gain anything by the fruit itself. This was also answered by Oda in one of the sbs questions.

> > D: WHAT HAPPENS IF A PERSON EATS A HITO HITO NO MI?[6]
>
> O: I suppose I should say they "BECOME HUMAN". Uh, I guess you could
>   say that means like becoming an adult, or finding your true spirit or
>   something. So basically, people will live more human-like. Well. I
>   guess you could say that. Or not. Basically, not. Goodbye. (runs
>   away).

http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_20

EDIT: maybe, the only thing a human would gain is the ability to ascend("to get to a higher state of consciousness") so one would be happy with himself, so to say. However this is just a speculation, and my take on it if something like that would happen and Oda would come up with a "power up" for the user

Comment: lol, even oda sensei didnt think about the possibility of this cases

Comment: I love how he said `finding your true spirit`. So in short, if a human eats it they know the secret of life itself.

Comment: Depend on the model actually. We know that Sengoku also eat Hito Hito no Mi, Model: Daibutsu and he can transform into a Buddha-like golden statue

Comment: @Darjeeling Yeah, but that's a Mythical Zoan DF  and not a regular like the Hito Hito no mi

Answer (score 4):

I think nothing will happen as such apart from one losing the ability swim.

But I believe it will only be for the base form. If the users use the fruit to its full potential, I believe a variation of Chopper's monster point can be achieved.

Also, *maybe* (a possibility a speculation), depending on how the fruit works, they might be able to transform into dwarfs, giants, long arm, long leg, etc. because all these are different races of the humans.

Also since there is awakening, which though has not been explained completely, it will be one more power obtained from the fruit.

Answer (score -1):

I guess that person will have enhanced knowledge and ability to alter his own body at will. or controlling your own muscle to the fullest

Comment: All of it will possible if the person who ate the fruit were a doctor, please note that copper caould be like what we know now because he made the rumble ball which can boost the user ability to the max, if not, he just like normal human being without a super power

Answer (score -1):

Oda answered this question in the [SBS](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS): he said that the person who ate the Devil Fruit "Hito Hito no Mi" will be more wise and intelligent than normal humans.